# Cache Key Not Found 'settings.xml' in DOCKER build

Tags: java, xml, docker, maven

Running Into a problem with my Maven 3.6.3 Docker Build with Java SDK 8 where it cannot find the .m2/settings.xml file correctly.

Here is the outputted error from the current docker build:

---

failed to compute cache key: "/settings.xml" not found: not found

---

Could somebody please help me problem solve what the correct thing to do with altering and copying the settings file with the linux command would be like?

```
# Custom image from Maven on DockerHub
# Language: dockerfile
FROM maven:3.6.3-amazoncorretto-8

# Set the working dir
RUN mkdir -p /app

# Create a non root user
ARG USERNAME=jefferson
ARG USER_UID=1000
ARG USER_GID=$USER_UID

# Add linux dependenciesq
RUN yum install wget -y
RUN yum install shadow-utils -y

ENV MAVEN_CONFIG=/var/maven/.m2

# Create the user
RUN groupadd --gid $USER_GID $USERNAME \
    && useradd --uid $USER_UID --gid $USER_GID -m $USERNAME \
    && yum install sudo -y \
    && echo $USERNAME ALL=\(root\) NOPASSWD:ALL > /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME \
    && chmod 600 /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME \
    && sudo groupadd docker \
    && sudo usermod -aG docker $USERNAME \
    && newgrp docker 

# Change to the root folder and edit the settings.xml for Maven
WORKDIR /var/maven/.m2
RUN rm -rf settings.xml \
    && chown $USER_UID:$USER_GID .
RUN echo '<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/0.0.0" \
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" \
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 \
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd"> \
</settings>' >> settings.xml

RUN find -name "settings.xml"

COPY settings.xml /root/.m2/settings.xml


COPY pom.xml ./pom.xml
COPY src ./ ./
COPY . ./

USER $USERNAME

# Run the application
CMD ["mvn", "clean", "verify", "-Duser.home=/var/maven", "-Pcargo.run", "-X"]
```

Comment: This is in reference to this line in the dockerfile:  
> [10/13] COPY settings.xml /root/.m2/settings.xml:

Comment: That error message usually means the `settings.xml` file doesn't exist on the host in the same directory as the Dockerfile (depending on how exactly you're building the image).

Comment: Yeah I understand that, there is just a particular and very complex config behind maven and docker in my opinion. It took me like 30 seconds to dockerize my node api.

Comment: Because the steps you have to go through are create a non root user, create a working dir, edit your maven file, copy your target, source, and pom, login to non root, and then run the mvn clean

Comment: And then there is the following command as well: docker run -v ~/.m2:/var/maven/.m2 -ti --rm -u 1000 -e MAVEN_CONFIG=/var/maven/.m2 maven:3.6.3-amazoncorretto-8 mvn -Duser.home=/var/maven paige-back:dev to properly run a maven project